# Running Python program, get message "Squeezed text"

Tags: python

I'm writing a Python 3.8 program for a Coursera algorithms course.  It reads in a file of 100,000 unsorted unique numbers, and that works fine.  Then it goes on to do a recursive merge sort, counting inversions.  The program is not working correctly, and I'm debugging with try: except IndexError: print structures, but when I made a change to avoid the index errors, it now gives only the message, "Squeezed text (6271 lines)".  What does that mean?  I searched for it in Idle Help and here on Stackoverflow, with no results.

Comment: Can you post a few lines of code around where the message happens?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in the text of your question, otherwise it's impossible to speculate

Comment: I found the answer.  I was trying to display the sorted array, instead of the number of inversions.